# Connection does not open in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g, oledb, oledbconnection

I need your help. I've been experiencing the "Connection not open" error lately on my Module, the funny thing is I didn't edit the code, it just suddenly appeared. Any ideas on what I should do?

I'm using Oracle Database 10g.

Here's the code:

```
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public dbProvider As String
Public dbSource As String

Public Sub connect()
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER = MSDAORA.1;"
    dbSource = "Data Source=localhost ; User Id=user ; Password=pass;"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open() '<------------ERROR

End Sub
```

Comment: where is the object con declared? where do you get the error? Is the connection string still connect (because you say you didn't change the code, it might be the data source)?

Comment: @slfan - I edited the post, I don't know if it is the data source though.

Comment: Are you sure that username and password are correct? Can you connect through Oracle software?